# How to implement a CPU level lock?

Tags: linux, optimization, multiprocessing, cpu-architecture

I want to implement a packet counter. Is it possible to restrict other cpu cores from reading or updating the counter variable, unless the current cpu completes its work on the counter variable? I want to do it at cpu level i.e. the lock I want to put is on cpu not on memory.
Primary goal is to make the counter variable atomic. I have read about locking mechanism and the best way I ended with is using per cpu variable. But, I want to implement packet counters entity wise for eg. I can say I want to count only those packets which have marked or something like that and in this case per cpu variable is not the best option. That is why I want to use a global counter variable and when that variable is being accessed by one of the core of cpu, I want to restrict other cores from accessing it.

Comment: Are you asking for an "atomic" variable?  Look up "atomic increment."  Any particular language or ISA?

Comment: "CPU level" implies "hardware" and the "kernel" implies "software." So you're asking for a mechanism you can implement in hardware that you can implement in software. I think you need to find a better way to phrase your question. Also, if I understand what it is you're trying to ask then you'll also need to explain why this data absolutely _must_ live in a register rather than in memory of any type.

Comment: @SanJacinto Yes! I want to put a locking mechanism with help of the hardware if possible. Frankly telling I have no idea on hardware operations, I am implementing a kernel module and if I can put a lock on CPU then overhead would be minimum.

Comment: Your edit helps, but you still haven't answered why the variable must live in CPU (i.e. consume a register) and not in memory. In the latter case, there are tons of libraries that have implemented an atomic increment already, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: OK, the kernel module context helps. Why can't you use the atomic increment functions that the kernel provides? Have you read anything on this topic, such as http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5833 ?

Comment: You mean core-level, not CPU-level, right? And you want this to live through context switches on that core? Why not just keep a global array indexed by physical core-id?

Comment: @SanJacinto Thanks! I checked out working of atomic_t variables and ultimately it provides atomicity through IRQ flags. That will do my work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Leeor I was not using global array because there is a chance of preemption. Per cpu variable takes care of preemption but in case of global array I would have to take care of it externally.